# asp.net web service reference object of object

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service
inside I use an entitie (object) as function parameter

but the class is "complex", 
I mean there object with object inside (simple OO)

```
class X
{
private Y;
...
} 

class Y
{
private Z;
...
}

class Z
{
int a;
...
}
```

so, my problem is that my service reference contain only X, so I cant se Y and Z, he didnt know what it is.

Is there a way to do it?

---

I have  `<WebMethod()`
Can I add something like `WebAttribute` ?

Comment: Are you classes marked as `Serializable`?

Comment: yes they're serializable

Comment: finally, the service know my other class, but he didnt initialize them. I need to do a new by myself for each one